# Vim global block move by patterns

Tags: vim, regex

I just came across this example in [Learning the vi and Vim Editors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/059652983X):

```
.Rh 0 "Get status of named file" "STAT"
.Rh "SYNTAX"
 ...
.Rh "DESCRIPTION"
 ...
.Rh "PARAMETERS"
 ...
```

The command to move DESCRIPTION above the SYNTAX paragraph is given by

```
:g /SYNTAX/.,/DESCRIPTION/-1 move /PARAMETERS/-1
```

The explanation given is: First, `ex` finds and marks each line that matches the first pattern. Second, for each marked line, it sets `.` (dot, the current line) to that line and executes the command.

But why do we need the dot after `/SYNTAX/`? Is it a special syntax for the `g` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:g` takes a command after its pattern. `:m` is the command, and it takes a range before it. `.` is the beginning of that range.

Comment: I see, so `:g` will automatically set `.` to the line that matches the pattern?

Comment: The pattern will become the current line being operated on.